# 引数とファイルのパスの比較

Tags: java

受け取った引数とあるフォルダに入ってるXMLファイルの先頭10文字を比較して一致するものを返すというメソッドを作りたいです。
ファイルが格納されている場所はC:\xmlとします
C:\xmlフォルダには
    AAAAAAAAAA.xml
    BBBBBBBBBB.xml
    CCCCCCCCCC.xml
の三つのXMLファイルが存在することにします。

```
public String filePathReturn(String fileId){
    //fileIdにAAAAAAAAAAが渡されたとき
    //C:\\xmlの三つのファイルと比較
    //一致するファイルパスを変数に格納
    String filePath = 上で一致したデータ(C:\\xml\\AAAAAAAAAA.xmlという形で)
    return filePath;
}
```

というものを作成したいのですが
決まったフォルダ内のファイル名との比較がわかりません
どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 指定フォルダ内のファイルパス一覧を取得して、パスからファイル名だけ抜きだして指定文字列の有無を正規表現でチェックするなぁ。

Comment: 豚吐露様>>
ありがとうございます。
一覧を取得、ファイル名だけ抜き出す指定文字の正規表現でひとつひとつ調べていくことにより何とか解決できそうです。

Answer (score 1):

Javaでは、ファイルもフォルダ(ディレクトリ)も、java.io.Fileクラスで扱えます。

例えば、`File f = new File("C:\\");`とすれば、変数 f はCドライブ直下のフォルダを参照します。

参照先がフォルダ（ディレクトリ）ですので、list()メソッドを使うことで、そのフォルダ(ディレクトリ内)のファイル名がStringの配列で取得できるでしょう。

あとはそのStringの配列の中から、合致するファイル名があるかを調べれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
無事解決いたしました。